# How do you make a toggle button with in a for loop?

Tags: c++, nucleo

I am working with a NUCLEO F401R0 micro-controller to make a clock. It has a physical button that outputs 1 when pressed through the "button" object I have initialized. There are 3 nested four loops that control hour, minute, and second incrementation. I am attempting to program a toggle button within the inner most for loop that controls seconds. When the the button is pressed I want to toggle between two variables that will be displayed out. How do I make a toggle operation within the inner most for loop while keeping the loops continuous?

```
int oldstate;
string unit;

DigitalIn  button(USER_BUTTON); 

for(int hh = 12; hh <= 13; hh++)
{

    for(int mm = 0; mm < 60; mm++)
    {

        for(int ss =0; ss < 60; ss++)
        {
            int currentState = button;

            if (currentState == 1 && oldState == 0) 
                {          
                    check = !check;
                }

            oldState = currentState ;

            if(check == 0)
                {
                    unit = "C";
                }
            else
                {
                    unit = "F";
                }


            cout << "\n\r Time: " << hh << ":" << mm << ":" << ss << " " << unit << flush;

        }
    }
}
```

The problem I currently have with the above code that is that it does 60 incrementations at once if I keep ss's incrementation in the for loop. I can solve this by incrementing when the button is pressed but that would mean a user would have to continuously click a button for the clock to operate.

Answer (score 1):

> it terminates the loop after one iteration.

No, it does not. It actually does all 59 iterations but on the same button state (too fast). In order to allow only 59 button clicks you simply need to increase the iteration on every new click. Here's how:

```
DigitalIn  button(USER_BUTTON); 

for ( int i = 0; i < 59 ; ) {
     int currentState = button;

      if (currentState == 1 && oldState == 0) {          
          check = !check;
          cout << "\r\n" << check << flush;

          ++i; // Here
      }

      oldState = currentState ;
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: That does work but is there anyway to have i increment outside of the if statement block. I'm planning on using the button toggle within 3 nested four loops and need them to run continuously. Essentially what I am doing is making a clock program, the outer most for loop counts up hour, followed by a for loop counting mins, and another counting seconds. I want to use the button toggle to switch between display functions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what you want to achieve. Can you edit the question with an example of this "3 nested for loops", then I can help you more.

Comment: I edited the question to add more details. The problem I'm having is where the in the inner most loop I should have ss increment in order to keep the clock continuous while also allowing the toggle operation to work.

Comment: Now, it's totally different. Don't confuse `for` loops with timers.